# Configuring HAProxy to route traffic based on url_param

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, haproxy, load-balance

I am very new to HAProxy. I spent a few hours trying to figure out how to do it but could not get any leads. My requirement is this:

If end point of request is /special then I need to check URL_PARAM.

> For example: localhost/special?id=10 Based on ID, I need to route it
>   to one of the 3 servers. If id <=3 server1, if id > 3 and id <=6
>   server2 else server3.

If end point is not /special round robin between all 3 servers.

How do I achieve this 2 level balancing?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `acl location_special path /special`
to match url and `acl srv_1 urlp_val(id) -m int eq 0:3`
to match on `id=` parameter. 
And finally

```
use-server server1 if location_special srv_1
```

to map request to certain server

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Would it work for large 64 bit numbers? Currently my ID ranges are like: "456304162255302657" to "456316501914435584". It doesn't seem to be working for it, although it works alright for smaller ranges.

Comment: I guess you need patch for Haproxy to work with such large numbers. Seems it will be easier to adjust your backends' logic to use lower IDs.